# How to increase speed of reading data on Windows using c++

Tags: c++, windows, performance, file-io, block

I am reading block of data from volume snapshot using `CreateFile/ReadFile` and buffersize of 4096 bytes.
The problem I am facing is `ReadFile` is too slow, I am able to read 68439 blocks i.e. 267 Mb in 45 seconds, How can I increase the speed? Below is a part of my code that I am using,

```
block_handle = CreateFile(block_file,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,NULL);
if(block_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD pos = -1;
    for(ULONG i = 0; i < 68439; i++)
    {
        sectorno = (i*8);
        distance = sectorno * sectorsize;
        phyoff.QuadPart = distance;     
        if(pos != phyoff.u.LowPart)
        {
             pos=SetFilePointer(block_handle, phyoff.u.LowPart,&phyoff.u.HighPart,FILE_BEGIN);
             if (phyoff.u.LowPart == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER && GetLastError() != NO_ERROR)
             {
                 printf("SetFilePointer Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
                 phyoff.QuadPart = -1;
                 return;
             }
        }
        ret = ReadFile(block_handle, data, 4096, &dwRead, 0);
        if(ret == FALSE)
        {
            printf("Error Read");
            return;
        }
        pos += 4096;
    }
}
```

Should I use `OVERLAPPED` structure? or what can be the possible solution?
**Note**: The code is not threaded.

Awaiting a positive response.

Comment: I see that the loop currently does essentially nothing - the data that you read is not used for anything. This leads me to think that you've omitted code which may be important to the answer. My immediate thoughts are **(a)** what does your profiler tell you? **(b)** is this significantly different to the result when profiling just the posted code? **(c)** what about memory-mapped file access, have you investigated that? Lastly, what is a typical value for `sectorSize` in this code?

Comment: @enhzflep: Yes I have omitted the other code which is to just dump the data in another volume. But I need to first test the speed, in my actual code also I have commented those lines and testing only the above code. I have not tried memory-mapped file access, can it be useful to read data from blocks/clusters as I dont know the file names. The sectorsize is 512.

Comment: I still wonder why you appear not to have run the code through a profiler!? (mingw & VS come with one) That will _tell_ you which part of the code is presenting a bottle-neck. - Not sure about the ins and outs of memory-mapped files, a quick check of MSDN indicates that `CreateFileMapping` takes a `HANDLE`, as is returned from a call to `CreateFile`. These may help: **1** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms810613.aspx **2** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx **3** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As for the sectorSize - your example shows sequential access of data. If the (last position of a read + 4096 bytes) == (new pos of a read) then do _not_ perform a seek operation.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494122/performance-issues-with-hard-disk-reading/1500389#1500389

Comment: @enhzflep: I have tried your way, not to perform seek operation If the (last position of a read + 4096 bytes) == (new pos of a read), but still the same result, the speed is not increased. I have posted a code related to it in reply to "CaptainCodeman's" post in this thread. Can you have a look to it?

Comment: @user3395981 - c'mon mate. That's rather unreadable, don't you think? You really should edit your question to include this code that you've tried in response to comments. If you provide some data from your profiler and edit your original post to include the code found in the comment you mention, I'd be happy to offer further thoughts. 45 seconds of running time should be ample to get a good idea. No reasonable, sane person will attempt to optimize without profiling their code first.

Comment: Hey @enhzflep Sorry for the inconvenience. I have edited my main question and added the code, have a look at it.

Comment: You're a programmer right? Surely you understand the meaning of **and**? Like I said: ["_If you provide some data from your profiler_ **and** edit your original post to include the code found in the comment you mention, I'd be happy to offer further thoughts"] Notice that I said **and** - I certainly did not say **or**!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you're using these extremely low level system functions for this.

Personally I have used C-style file operations (using fopen and fread) as well as C++-style operations (using fstream and read, see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)), to read raw binary files.  From a local disk the read speed is on the order of 100MB/second.

In your case, if you don't want to use the standard C or C++ file operations, my guess is that the reason your code is slower is due to the fact that you're performing a seek after each block.  Do you really need to call SetFilePointer for every block?  If the blocks are sequential you shouldn't need to do this.

Also, experiment with different block sizes, don't be afraid to go up and beyond 1MB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I only know the block numbers so that is why I am using low level system functions, I dont know the filenames. Incase if my blocks are sequential and if I dont call `SetFilePointer` for every block than how the `ReadFile` function will come to know from where to read? Can you please explain with short code or example related to `SetFilePointer`? And also I need to read only 4096 byes of data at a time, so at present can't increase the blocksize.

Comment: In different computers I have & had, I always get the best speed reading 64k blocks. Also, as @CaptainCodeman says, try to avoid the seek operation.

Comment: Also to tell you, the blocks may be sequential but not necessary I need to read all the blocks. For eg: after reading 1000th block I may be reading 1500th block and skipping the blocks between 1000-1500.

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri: That is what I am asking, how can I avoid seek operation, as I dont know the next block number in the list, as I already mentioned in my previous comment. Can you direct me to a sample or code that I can refer? Also I know that increasing blocksize may increase speed but I have to read only 4096 bytes of data, can't increase it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you trying to read directly from a filesystem and extract files, etc. from that?  Is it the case that the data is scattered in 4K blocks around the volume and you need to read one in order to find out where the next one is?  If that's the case your data is fragmented, and there really isn't a fast way to read fragmented data. (That's why people defragment their filesystems.)  If your data is mostly sequential, ReadFile updates the file pointer so you don't need to seek to read the next block.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I have to read those blocks whose bits are set in the bitmap. So you can say sequential but not necessary the very next block I have to read, I have mentioned it in my previous comments too. And yes the data is scattered in 4k blocks around the volume.

Comment: Did you try with the FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS flag?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: I have tried your way by not seeking every time but than too the speed is same, I have edited my main question and added the code, have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the fragmented data reads.  You cannot solve this by fiddling with ReadFile parameters.  You need to defragment your reads.  here are three approaches:

1. Defragment the data on the disk
2. Defragment the reads.  That is, collect all the reads you need, but do not read anything yet.  Sort the reads into order.  Read everything in order, skipping the SetFilePointer wherever possible ( i.e. sequential blocks ).  This will speed the total read greatly, but introduce a lag before the first read starts.
3. Memory map the data.  Copy ALL the data into memory and do random access reads from memory.  Whether or not this is possible depends on how much data there is in total.

Also, you might want to get fancy, and experiment with caching.  When you read a block of data, it might be that although the next read is not sequential, it may well have a high probability of being close by.  So when you read a block, sequentially read an enormous block of nearby data into memory.  Before the next read, check if the new read is already in memory - thus saving a seek and a disk access.  Testing, debugging and tuning this is a lot of work, so I do not really recommend it unless this is a mission critical optimization.  Also note that your OS and/or your disk hardware may already be doing something along these lines, so be prepared to see no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your first approach won't work for me and the third one too. As a partition can be of any size may be of 10gb or 100gb or 1tb, so the third approach won't work. I will try the second approach and will again let you know.

Comment: What you mean by "experimenting with caching and sequentially read an enormous block of nearby data", you mean to say storing the new block position or copying the next data block into memory? By the way I tried storing the next block position and comparing it with new block position and if same then avoiding the seek operation, but it did not helped, still the speed is same. I have edited my main question and added the new code, have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

1. If possible, read sequentially (and tell CreateFile you intend to read sequentially with `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN`).
2. Avoid unnecessary seeks.  If you're reading sequentially, you shouldn't need any seeks.
3. Read larger chunks (like an integer multiple of the typical cluster size).  I believe Windows's own file copy uses reads on the order of 8 MB rather than 4 KB.  Consider using an integer multiple of the system's allocation granularity (available from GetSystemInfo).
4. Read from aligned offsets (you seem to be doing this).
5. Read to a page-aligned buffer.  Consider using VirtualAlloc to allocate the buffer.
6. Be aware that fragmentation of the file can cause expensive seeking.  There's not much you can do about this.
7. Be aware that volume compression can make seeks especially expensive because it may have to decompress the file from the beginning to find the starting point in the middle of the file.
8. Be aware that volume encryption might slow things down.  Not much you can do but be aware.
9. Be aware that other software, like anti-malware, may be scanning the entire file every time you touch it.  Fewer operations will minimize this hit.